# Grails get list of A's where searching with B's in many to many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain objects:

```
class Blog {
   String foo
}

class Comment {
   String bar
}

class BlogComment {
   Blog blog
   Comment comment
}
```

So far I've written this:

```
def getComments(Blog blog) {
    def blogCommentCriteria = BlogComment.createCriteria()

    def blogCommentResults = blogCommentCriteria.list {
        eq 'blog.id', blog.id
    }

    List<Comment> comments = new Vector<Blog>()

    blogCommentResults.each { i ->
        if(i.blog == blog) {
            comments.add(i.comment)
        }
    }

    comments
}
```

What would be the most efficient method? I want the method to be clean and simple, but also efficient in terms of time taken.

Comment: That looks very broken, but maybe not. It looks like you're doing a partial filter on `blog.id`, but then doing client-side secondary filtering (`i.blog == blog`) which is a great example of how to do bad database queries. Always do as much filtering in the database as possible. But you're checking what you used previously in the query, right? You get all of the `BlogComment`s for the specified `Blog`, then loop through and only keep the ones that are for the specified `Blog`? Unrelated but surprising - what's up with that `Vector`? That's not a class that is well-known for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to the Blog class to get the comments associated with a given blog:

```
class Blog {
   String foo

   def getComments() {
        BlogComment.findAllByBlog(this)*.comment
   }
}
```